# How to search in Firebase Realtime database if you have a huge node?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, out-of-memory, binary-search

I have a node that contains lots of data like **20MB** and I need to search for a specific string in that node.

So I just wrote a Cloud Function to achieve this but it's **consuming too much memory**. So I asked a friend of mine and he suggested this:

> download the file to your local server daily and then use binary search on requests.

This is doable and makes sense to me but if you guys have a better idea I really would like to hear.

How can I search for a specific string in a 20MB file with NodeJS?

Comment: is your node value a string ? or it is an object with many children that hold the data you have to check ? The cloud function you have wrote can be useful to look at for a better answer :)

Comment: It's an object array that contains almost 20 childrens. And I need to check for single children